# How to wait for full completion of a completable future with runAsync?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

This test fails:

```
package com.stackoverflow.demo;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AsyncTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Assert.assertTrue("please run this test in a machine with 2 or more cores", ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism() > 1);

        CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("ok");
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> out = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

        cf.thenRunAsync(() -> {
            out.add("one");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            out.add("two");
        }, ForkJoinPool.commonPool());

        cf.join();

        Assert.assertEquals(2, out.size());
    }

}
```

I was surprised because I expected `cf.join()` to take all attached tasks into account. I am sure it says somewhere in the documentation that `join` only waits for the initial task, but somehow I missed it.

How can I get the behavior I want: **Wait for a CompletableFuture and all its attached subtasks to complete**?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it while proof-reading my post:

```
public class AsyncTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Assert.assertTrue("please run this test in a machine with 2 or more cores", ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism() > 1);

        CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("ok");
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> out = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

        CompletableFuture<Void> cf2 = cf.thenRunAsync(() -> {
            out.add("one");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            out.add("two");
        }, ForkJoinPool.commonPool());

        cf2.join();

        Assert.assertEquals(2, out.size());
    }

}
```